# Remove a just created object on AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a list of searches.

*search.html:*

```
<ul class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="search in searchesCtrl.searches">
    <li>
      <a href="#">{{search.url}}</a><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="searchesCtrl.deleteSearch(search)">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchesCtrl.newSearch.name"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchesCtrl.newSearch.url"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
         <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="searchesCtrl.addNewSearch()">Go</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

*search.controller.js:*

```
'use strict';

(function () {

class SearchesComponent {
  constructor($http) {
     this.$http = $http;
     this.searches = [];
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.$http.get('/api/searches')
      .then(response => {
        this.searches = response.data;
      });
  }

  addNewSearch() {
    if (this.newSearch) {
      this.$http.post('/api/searches', {
        url: this.newSearch.url,
        name: this.newSearch.name
      }).then(() => {
        this.searches.push(this.newSearch);
        this.newSearch = '';
      });
    }
  }

  deleteSearch(search) {
    this.$http.delete('/api/searches/' + search._id)
      .then(() => {
        this.searches.splice(this.searches.indexOf(search),1);
      });
  }
}

angular.module('myApp')
  .component('searches', {
    templateUrl: 'app/searches/searches.html',
    controller: SearchesComponent,
    controllerAs: 'searchesCtrl'
  });
})();
```

If I try to remove a search that I just have added, without refreshing the page, it's not working.
The `ng-click="searchesCtrl.deleteSearch(search)"` is calling
`/api/searches/undefined`.

I try to work without the $index solution. Is it possible ?

Comment: In which part of your `function` are you getting `undefined`?

Comment: the object parameter "search._id" is undefined because it just have been created.

Comment: Does your server return newly created objects on `$http.post('/api/searches'..).then(newSearch => ...`? You need to get `search._id` from the server somehow.

Comment: Yes, you have to get this id after `$http.post` in your `addNewSearch` `function`, otherwise your `delete` willn't work.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko & developer033 I have that in my my answer.. but have deleted it because I was little bit confused with OP. Now by looking at comments I confirmed that my thought was right. So added my answer back. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the newly added `search` doesn't seems to have `_id` parameter, as you are directly pushing only `this.newSearch` in `searches` array.

Basically your add new post method should return a object entity which has saved in Database & that will have correct `_id` populated by server. Next, push that new entity object to `searches` array. Still I personally feel this approach very bad, as we are assuming that only one user going to handle this system. As we're giving responsibility to update `searches` object in javascript only.

Here we go, rather than maintaining thing locally, I'd say that, you should re-run get call to fetch all `searches` which you're already doing `$onInit` function. So it will make ensure that the list you are seeing on UI is synced with server. You must call `getSearches` method when you are deleting and saving object which is proper way of doing it.

**Code**

```
class SearchesComponent {
  constructor($http) {
     this.$http = $http;
     this.searches = [];
  }

  getSearches(){
    this.$http.get('/api/searches')
      .then(response => {
        this.searches = response.data;
      });
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.getSearches(); //retrieving list of searches from server
  }

  addNewSearch() {
    if (this.newSearch) {
      this.$http.post('/api/searches', {
        url: this.newSearch.url,
        name: this.newSearch.name
      }).then(() => {
        this.getSearches(); //asking for list from server
      });
    }
  }

  deleteSearch(search) {
    this.$http.delete('/api/searches/' + search._id)
      .then(() => {
        this.getSearches(); //asking for list from server.
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: @JulienMalige look at the updated code.. I changed my approach slightly, previous wasn't proper per me.. please check the code as well and follow those steps, Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for the code. "Still I personally feel this approach very bad", what is your alternative solution ? A refresh ?

Comment: @JulienMalige yes, you should refresh `searches`, sorry for confusion, I had that in my answer, now I did format it again.. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, this is for me the good way to do what I want. I am using the yo angular-fullstack generator and some tutorials. Codes are not using the same practices, someones contain bugs...